# Trimming my inputs before validating?

Tags: php, validation

I have some questions about my server-side validation script.Currently, i validate my input data by checking if the fields in the $_POST array are empty, of if they are shorter than the min length.

My script(extract);

```
if(!isset($_POST['BizAddItemCat']) OR empty($_POST['BizAddItemCat']))
{
    die("Please enter a category for your item.");
}

if(!isset($_POST['BizAddItemSubCat']) OR empty($_POST['BizAddItemSubCat']))
{
    die("Please enter a subcategory for your item");
}

if(!isset($_POST['BizAddItemName']) OR empty($_POST['BizAddItemName']) OR strlen($_POST['BizAddItemName']) < 5)
{
    die("Your item name must contain at least 5 characters");
}

if(!isset($_POST['BizAddItemPrice']) OR empty($_POST['BizAddItemPrice']))
{
    die("Your item must have a price");
}

if(!isset($_POST['BizAddItemQty']) OR empty($_POST['BizAddItemQty']))
{
    die("You must enter your available stock for your item");
}

if(!isset($_POST['BizAddItemDesc']) OR empty($_POST['BizAddItemDesc']) OR strlen($_POST['BizAddItemDesc']) < 20)
{
    die("Your item description must contain at least 20 characters");
}
```

I then trim the $_POST variables and assign them to variables

```
$itemcat=trim($_POST['BizAddItemCat']);
$itemsubcat=trim($_POST['BizAddItemSubCat']);
$itemname=trim($_POST['BizAddItemName']);
$itemprice=trim($_POST['BizAddItemPrice']);
$itemqty=trim($_POST['BizAddItemQty']);
$itemdesc=trim($_POST['BizAddItemDesc']);
```

However, a string with all spaces (e.g "           " ), will pass the empty() check but all the spaces will be removed by trim(). Therefore if i have a string with all spaces passed in, it would pass my validation and will have all the spaces removed, leaving me with an empty variable?

However, if i trim my variables before validating them, then i wouldn't be able to check if the fields exist (isset($_POST['etc'])?

If so, how would i go about addressing this?

Comment: First trim then check for empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either trim the value before it goes through the condition, or, change the condition to check for an empty string.

```
if ($_POST['whatevervalue'] !== " ")
```

I would suggest going with trimming before the condition. Although why you're assignment statements come after the checks is confusing me.

Comment: when i tested out my script,if i trim the inputs by using (e.g $a=trim($_POST['dsadasdas'])) and then checking with isset(), it always returns $a as true( isset() passes ) but when i remove the trim,isset() returns false. SO i though that i would assign the variables after checking if the inputs exists are are !empty.By trimming before validating, my isset() will not be working?

Comment: Are you sure the values are being set properly?